# Optimize Selection of Columns that Maximize Correlation in R

Tags: r, optimization, correlation

I am struggling with a programming issue. The goal is to find the optimal mean aggregate of multiple columns, such that that aggregate column maximizes the correlation with another column.

As a toy example, consider the following data:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- cbind(data.frame(FIRM = rnorm(36, 0, 0.05)),
              data.frame(matrix(rnorm(36 * 50, 0, 0.05), 36, 50)))
```

Thus: the goal is to find the optimal combination of the 50 "X" columns such that when taking rowmeans of these columns the correlation with the "FIRM" column is maximized. However, altough this is only a small example, there are already 50 factorial possible combinations.

Part of the issue is that the real dataset is much larger (i.e., around 20,000 "FIRM" optimizations, with over 5,000 "X" possible columns to aggregate per optimization). Up until now, I started with some stepwise optimizations, but given the size of the dataset this is very inefficient. I was hoping to get some insights in a better way of coding this issue.

So far I wrote some code that takes any linear combination and maximizes that correlation with the initial column. However, I would now like to adjust this, such that the code does **not** weigh the columns by any other weights than 1 or 0.

The code I have so far is:

```
set.seed(123)

firm <- rnorm(36, 0, 0.05)
peers <- matrix(rnorm(36 * 50, 0, 0.05), 36, 50)

#Function to maximize
cor.model <- function(w = rep(1 / ncol(peers), ncol(peers))){
  f_score <- peers %*% (w / sum(w))
  x <- f_score
  y <- firm
  correl <- cor(x,y)
  return(correl)
}

#Output
out <- optim(par = rep(1 / ncol(peers), ncol(peers)),
             fn = cor.model,
             method = "L-BFGS-B",
             lower = rep(0, ncol(peers)), # W_i >= 0 for all i
             upper = rep(1, ncol(peers)), # W_i <= 1 for all i)
             control = list(fnscale = -1))

out$par/sum(out$par)

cor(firm, rowSums(peers))
cor(firm, rowSums(t(as.vector(out$par/sum(out$par))*t(peers))))
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "equal-weighted aggregate"?  Would any linear combination of the columns be ok, or do you need only simple sums?  (E.g., `X1+X2` is ok, but `X1+(X2/3)` is not.)

Comment: Sorry, with equal-weighted I meant that we either include the column or we do not; so only "simple sums." Then, I would like to aggregate all columns to 1 column by simply taking the mean of those columns that are selected, and maximize the correlation with the other column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try a Local Search (as described in this [tutorial](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391756)).

Here is a sketch in R.

```
FIRM <- as.matrix(df[[1]])
M <- as.matrix(df[, -1])

library("neighbours")  ## https://github.com/enricoschumann/neighbours
library("NMOF")        ## https://github.com/enricoschumann/NMOF

N <- neighbourfun(type = "logical", kmin = 1, kmax = 50)
```

An initial solution.

```
x <- logical(50)
x[1:5] <- TRUE
```

The objective function. The function we use later minimises, so I put a minus in front of the computation.

```
of_cor <- function(x, FIRM, M) {
    -c(cor(FIRM, rowMeans(M[, x])))
}
```

Test: select all 50 columns.

```
-of_cor(!logical(50), FIRM, M)
## [1] -0.1727944
```

Test: use the initial solution.

```
-of_cor(x, FIRM, M)
## [1] -0.2261783
```

Run the actual computation, with Threshold Accepting (which is based on Local Search).

```
sol <- TAopt(of_cor,
             list(x0 = x,
                  neighbour = N,
                  nI = 50000),
             M = M,
             FIRM = FIRM)
## Threshold Accepting
## [....]
##   Finished.
##   Best solution overall: -0.6206239
```

The solution has a correlation of 0.62.

```
-of_cor(sol$xbest, FIRM, M)
## [1] 0.6206239
```

(Disclosure: I am the maintainer of the packages that I used.)

Comment: That is an elegent piece of code. Thanks a lot! Just one follow-up question, given that in my real dataset "M" contains over 5,000 columns, is there any way to also restrict the optimal M size to say 50?

Comment: Right now, this happens automatically through the way in which the neighbourhood is defined (`neighbourfun`): you define the minimum and maximum `TRUE` values through `kmin` and `kmax`. You only need  to make sure that the initial solution is valid.